# this javaScript code to scan QR by webcam the code work perfect on the localhost but when upload to realhost on webserver the camer did not open

Tags: javascript, html

This javaScript code to scan QR by a webcam the code work perfect on the localhost but when uploading to real host on the webserver the camera did not open

## QR

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
     let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
      scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
        alert(content);

      });
      ****Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
        if (cameras.length > 0) {
          scanner.start(cameras[0]);

        } else {
          console.error('No cameras found.');
          document.write("error");

        }
      }).catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e);
        document.write("catch");

      });

  document.write(content);
  document.write("hello");

</script>
```

Comment: It could be the browser/user did not authorize access to the camera

Comment: read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Privacy_and_security

Comment: You've written some content to the console and screen in your code - please provide some help to us by telling us what the output was in both console and browser.

Comment: sorry  .. in the localhost the page work perfect open the webcam andread the QR
but when upload to realhost the webcam not work and print  "catch" word